# How to replace XML property name value

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have the following XML:

```
<resources xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <resource id="kig" type="com.ac.resourcedata.xml" site="ki">
    <property name="name1">value1</property>
    <property name="name2">value2</property>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

I need to modify value1 to something else,
and the following Perl script is what I could compose so far:

```
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $twig=XML::Twig->new(   
    twig_handlers => { 
        parameter  => sub {
            if ($_->att('name') eq 'name1') {
                ->set_att(new value) 
            }
        }
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
);

$twig->parsefile($file);

$twig->print(\*XMLOUT) or
die "Failed to write modified XML file:$!\n";

close XMLOUT;

$twig->flush();
```

But nothing changes!
Any idea is really appreciated.

Regards,
Behzad

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code:

- it doesn't compile: `->set_att` is not a valid statement
- using `use warnings` would let you know that there's something wrong wit XMLOUT, you would get `print() on unopened filehandle XMLOUT`, if you want to output to a file, use `print_to_file`
- your handler is on `parameter`, when the element you want to update is called `property`, and actually you can even specify that you only want to update `property` when the attribute name is `name1` directly in the handler trigger: `property[@name="name1"]`
- it looks like what you want is to change the text of the property, not an attribute

After fixing all of this, you get

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie qw( open);

use XML::Twig;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $twig=XML::Twig->new(   
    twig_handlers => { 
        'property[@name="name1"]'  => sub { $_->set_text('value') }
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
);

$twig->parsefile($file);
$twig->print_to_file( $file);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set up an `XML::Twig` handler for `parameter` elements, but there are non in your data so nothing gets modified.

In addition

- `use strict` is good, but you should also `use warnings`
- You never open a file on the `XMLOUT` handle. It is simpler to use the module's `print_to_file` method to avoid having to open a file yourself

What I *think* you want to do is to look for `name` attributes of `property` elements and set them to something else if they are currently equal to `name`.

This code will do that for you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my ($file) = @ARGV;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(   
    twig_handlers => { 
        property => sub {
            if ($_->att('name') eq 'name1') {
                $_->set_att(name => 'something else');
            }
        }
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented',
);

$twig->parsefile($file);

$twig->print_to_file('xmlout.xml');
```

**output**

```
<resources xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <resource id="kig" site="ki" type="com.ac.resourcedata.xml">
    <property name="something else">value1</property>
    <property name="name2">value2</property>
  </resource>
</resources>
```